# Maven repo for BigInsights / IOP

Tags: hadoop, biginsights, hadoop-2.7.2

I have a IBM BigInsights 4.2 cluster installed and I am trying to create native yarn jobs.

To compile the java code on my laptop (not on the cluster), I need the hadoop client libraries.

How can I get the hadoop java libraries for IBM BigInsigths 4.2 (IOP)?

At the same time, my java project use Maven. Is there a Maven repo for the BigInsights 4.2 (IOP) java libraries?

Comment: I don't think IBM provides a public maven repo, but since Biginsights (aka IOP) is shipping open source hadoop (plus fixes and improvements), the library should have no difference with same version apache hadoop, it should be OK you can use apache repo for client development.